# css class not working, in a css file, but in a style tag yes

Tags: html, css

i have a problem if i put the code

```
        <style>
            .MyClass123 {
                content: url("img/ic_datos_activo_48px.png");
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 30px;
            }
        </style>

        <div style="float: left;position:absolute; right:0">
            <img class="MyClass123"/>
        </div>
```

there is worked, but if i put the css class in a css file, not work. in the html document there's are other class, but they works

Comment: This is not a valid use of the [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property. You can only use it with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't differentiate between inline, in-page or linked styles. If results between those methods differ, the reason is either erroneous including of the external file or the load order of your CSS, neither of which could be judged from the info in your question.

Furthermore, there are several problems and things to improve with the code in your question:

- As @FrédéricHamidi commented, you're not using the [content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) as you should - it's only valid use is within `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.
- Your [`img` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) doesn't have a `src` attribute, and possibly should have an `alt` attribute as well (since this isn't part of the question, I won't go into great detail, but a good description can be found on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).
- Since you're using a CSS file to store your page styles, you shouldn't rely on inline styles whatsoever. Instead, add the respective attributes to those elements and address them via CSS selectors. This will give you long-time maintainability, good task management (HTML files structure content, CSS files handle display) and won't look like your first HTML page.
- There is very little chance you actually need the `float` property on an absolute positioned element.

---

That being said, since you're apparently trying to set a background image, here is the code you would need for that:

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
    .MyClass123 {
      background-image: url("img/ic_datos_activo_48px.png");
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 30px;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="MyClass123"></div>
</div>
```

If instead you need the image to be a part of the document flow, use the `img` element for that purpose. If you need to change those with CSS (this would mostly be the case if you did some JS manipulation), a clean way to do it would be to creature multiple image elements and hide them as needed:

```
<style>
    .image2, .image3 {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <img class="image1" src="img1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
    <img class="image2" src="img2.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
    <img class="image3" src="img3.jpg" alt="Image 3" />
</div>
```

If you need to set the `src` to a previously unknown value entirely, you would be better off solving this via JS anyway, as **CSS is for design purposes, not for content manipulation** (with a handful of exceptions, yours not being one of them). For completeness' sake, here's a jQuery one-liner on how to tackle the problem:

```
$('.MyClass123').attr('src', 'new_url.jpg');
```

Comment: i want change the image dinamically, it's not a background, is a "icon-image"

Comment: @IvanParedes: Where is the dynamic in setting a fix in a URL file vs. in an `img`'s source attribute? For what purpose are you attempting to solve this the way you did? As I said, the way you're solving it isn't a solution you should implement, even if you found a browser in which this works the way you want. It's not a part of any standard.

Comment: I just want to change the image if a variable is true and if it is false to put another image

Comment: @IvanParedes: As I said previously, CSS doesn't have any variables and won't be fit for "dynamic" output, so you either control the output server-side (i.e. with PHP), in which case the background-image solution will apply. If instead you set it client-side (i.e. with JS), it would be easiest to set it directly instead via the solution in the last code block within my answer. If you need more detailed explanations, please clarify it by adding more information to your question, and I'll be happy to extend my answer!

Comment: thank you. my english is very poor. anyway your are a genious

Comment: @IvanParedes: Does that mean your question is answered then? If so, please accept an answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue; otherwise please clarify what you still need to know!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
.MyClass123 {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 30px;
   float: left;
   position:absolute; 
   right:0
}

<div>
    <img class="MyClass123" alt="Image" src="img/ic_datos_activo_48px.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: i wanted change the image dinamically via css